# Using antiderivatives to find velocity given acceleration with a domain

Tags: calculus, integration

If the acceleration is:

> $a = 9 - 0.9t$ if 0 ≤ t ≤ 10
> $a = 0$ if t > 10

Which function of a do I use to find the velocity? On my attempt, I had two separate antiderivatives (one for each domain), but it did not get me the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$v=\int a ~dt$$
So for $0\le t\le10$, $v=9t-0.45t^2+c$ for some constant $c$, and for $t>10$, the velocity is constant, so it is equal to $d$ for some other constant $d$
(which could be numerically equal to $c$).

Comment: What do you mean by "which could be numerically equal to $c$"?

Comment: @mfl I mean that $c$ and $d$ don't necessarily have to be different.

Comment: @mfl please let me know if anything is bothering you and I will try to explain it.

Comment: So there will be two separate functions for s(t) as well?

Comment: @RudyGoburt There are not two separate functions. A function is not necessarily just one simple algebraic expression like $9t−0.45t^2$. It is possible for a function to be defined by one expression in part of its domain and a different expression in another part of its domain. It is also possible for a function to be defined in such a complicated way that you cannot write its definition with any finite number of simple algebraic expressions.